# dropzone.js function getQueuedFiles causes "too much recursion"

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, dropzone.js

I'm using [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) and I'm trying to check if there are still files in queue.

I have got a form with a dropzone.
By clicking on the form's submit button the files should get uploaded first and then the form should be submitted.
My JavaScript code looks like this:

```
var fileDropzone = new Dropzone(document.getElementById('fileDropzone'),
    {
        url: uploadUrl,
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        autoDiscover: false,
        dictDefaultMessage: transUploadFiles
    }
);
var success = false;

$('form.uploadForm').submit(function (e) {
    var that = this;
    var filesInQueue = fileDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length;

    if (!success && filesInQueue > 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        fileDropzone.processQueue();
        fileDropzone.on("success", function () {
            fileDropzone.options.autoProcessQueue = true;
        });
        fileDropzone.on("queuecomplete", function (file) {
            success = true;
            $(that).submit();
        });
    }
});
```

To check if there are files in the queue I use the function getQueuedFiles(), but this causes the error "too much recursion" in the console.

Using an if statement like the following, causes the console.log to appear 321 times if there are no files in queue.

```
if(fileDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
    console.log("no files in queue");
}
```

Did I do something wrong or is there another possibility to check if there are still files in queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `$(that).submit();` with POJS `that.submit();`, which is guaranteed to submit the form without retriggering the onsubmit handler.